# Python Selenium - Extract Instagram hashtags from a Photo

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

I have a problem with extracting the hashtags from a selected photo

the code I'm workin now is

```
<a class=" abcd" href="/explore/tags/ht1/" tabindex="0">#ht1</a>
<a class=" abcd" href="/explore/tags/ht2/" tabindex="0">#ht2</a>
<a class=" abcd" href="/explore/tags/ht3/" tabindex="0">#ht3</a>
<a class=" abcd" href="/explore/tags/ht4/" tabindex="0">#ht4</a>
```

So I need to place them on a list, so I write

```
tags = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('abcd')
```

And that works, I can actually can print the list and check for the exact number of Ht

But when I do

```
tags[0].text
```

Only executes a white line and I need to print "#ht1"
I tested that with other single classes and it worked, I'm thinking that the problem is about printing a list.

Comment: are these elements visible when you are requesting to retrieve their text?  If not, you'll get blanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to wait for the page to load and the elements to become visibile.

```
tags = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('abcd')
```

replace with

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"abcd")))
```

imports

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Do you know if extracting hashtags from a phone is doable using the API?