# Instagram - get hashtags of a photo/video

Tags: web-scraping, instagram, instagram-graph-api

Given a media ID of a content on Instagram, I want to know the hashtags associated with it. I had a good look at the official [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media) but I can't seem to find a way to do this.

There is this [related question from about a year back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66356333/python-selenium-extract-instagram-hashtags-from-a-photo) but it uses Python Selenium.

Is there a way to do this using the API? Or are scrapers the way to go?

Comment: In which language do you want it?

Comment: Python, JavaScript, all languages are good. But I'd prefer doing via the API than scraping.